# Symbols for ascending union/descending intersection

Tags: symbols

When writing on paper or on blackboard, I usually denote an ascending union by `\bigcup` with an upwards arrow at the end of the right prong. Likewise, I denote a descending intersection by `\bigcap` with a downwards arrow at the end of the right prong. Are these symbols included in any standard packages? If not, how can I define them?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
    \[
        (0,1)=\bigcup_n \left[\frac1n, 1-\frac1n\right]
    \]
    
    \[
        \{0\}=\bigcap_n \left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope to remember well. IMHO the symbols with the arrows not exist. I think that they should be created.

Comment: Unrelated but do not use the `minimal` class for MWEs: despite the name it is not suited. Use `article` instead.

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/82917)

Comment: @campa: Still, wouldn't `standalone` be better than `article`? Or does it have similar problems?

Comment: `standalone` loads `article` (unless you choose a different class with the appropriate option).

Comment: @campa: I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\DeclareMathOperator*\dcap{{\stackinset{r}{-1.02ex}{c}{-1.9pt}{\downarrow}
  {\bigcap}\mkern2mu}}
\DeclareMathOperator*\acup{{\stackinset{r}{-1.02ex}{c}{1.9pt}{\uparrow}
  {\bigcup}\mkern2mu}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        (0,1)=\acup_n \left[\frac1n, 1-\frac1n\right]
    \]
    
    \[
        \{0\}=\dcap_n \left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you were always to be using it in `\displaystyle`, one could adapt to it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\DeclareMathOperator*\dcap{{\stackinset{r}{-1ex}{c}{-3.1pt}{\downarrow}
  {\displaystyle\bigcap}\mkern2mu}}
\DeclareMathOperator*\acup{{\stackinset{r}{-1ex}{c}{3.1pt}{\uparrow}
  {\displaystyle\bigcup}\mkern2mu}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        (0,1)=\acup_n \left[\frac1n, 1-\frac1n\right]
    \]
    
    \[
        \{0\}=\dcap_n \left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice....They are perfects.

Comment: @tomasz It works for me...stackengine 2017/02/13 v4.01, using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit).  See https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine for latest version.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I had a broken miktex installation. Fixing it now, should be okay. Still, I guess this is not going to work on arXiv for a while. :(

Answer (score 4):

The symbols look much more like U-turns on a road sign, to be honest.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ubigcup}{\DOTSB\mathop{\,\ubigcup@\,}\slimits@}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dbigcap}{\DOTSB\mathop{\,\dbigcap@\,}\slimits@}

\newcommand{\ubigcup@}{\mathpalette\ubigcup@@\relax}
\newcommand{\ubigcup@@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\bigcup$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\uparrow$}%
  \copy\z@
  \mkern-6.3mu\ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\mkern0.3mu\fi
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\z@-\ht\tw@
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\else
    \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\advance\dimen@ 0.5pt\else
      \advance\dimen@ 1pt
  \fi\fi
  \raisebox{\dimen@}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\copy\tw@}}%
  \mkern6.3mu\ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-0.3mu\fi
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\dbigcap@}{\mathpalette\dbigcap@@\relax}
\newcommand{\dbigcap@@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\bigcap$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\downarrow$}%
  \copy\z@
  \mkern-6.3mu\ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\mkern0.3mu\fi
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\dp\z@-\dp\tw@
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\else
    \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\advance\dimen@ 0.5pt\else
      \advance\dimen@ 1pt
  \fi\fi
  \raisebox{-\dimen@}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\copy\tw@}}%
  \mkern6.3mu\ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-0.3mu\fi
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\ubigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$
$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$

\bigskip

$\textstyle\ubigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$
$\scriptstyle\ubigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$
$\scriptscriptstyle\ubigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$

\bigskip

$\displaystyle\dbigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$
$\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$

$\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$

\bigskip

$\textstyle\dbigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$
$\scriptstyle\dbigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$
$\scriptscriptstyle\dbigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Small issue: in the displaystyle version, the alignment of $\infty$ and $n=1$ are a bit misaligned.

Comment: @tomasz That's an optical effect due to the arrow. If you check the picture, you'll see that the infinity symbols are perfectly aligned with each other. To be honest, I'll restrain from using such symbols.

Comment: My point is that I think it would look better with the symbols aligned with the cup/cap, not the whole symbol including the arrow.

Comment: @tomasz I don't understand: the subscripts and superscripts are in the same exact position with or without the arrow.

Comment: In the third line from the bottom,  on the right, the middle of the $\infty$ sign is right above the top of the cap, and on the left, it is shifted towards the right.

Comment: @tomasz OK, now I see. I'll fix in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!